# Getting Websocket error: unsuccessful close in Jmeter

Tags: websocket, jmeter

I am working on a Websocket load testing using JMeter. I am able to create a connection and even the Write and Read Sampler are working fine. But the Close sampler is failing. The response code says **unsuccessful close**. Response message says **received not a close frame, but Text frame with text**. Am I doing anything wrong here?
Below is the screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a functional defect in the system you're testing.

As per [specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455.html#section-5.5.1):

> If an endpoint receives a Close frame and did not previously send a
> Close frame, the endpoint MUST send a Close frame in response.

So most probably you need to raise a defect and describe the situation. It would be good if you add request and response details, they can be obtained from [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) given you [enable JMeter debug logging](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-logging) for websocket plugin by adding the next line to *log4j2.xml* file:

```
<Logger name="eu.luminis" level="debug" />
```